new static web-app is not updated in azure storage
Using flutter I build a sample web-app (default one when you create project in flutter).
using
flutter build web command 

I uploaded the web folder with index.html in static web-app in azure storage and enabled the static web app it worked. I'm able to view the web application in chrome.
later I created another one but the web-app as I required like dashboard, followed the same command to build for web and uploaded the files. When I run the same URL sometimes it opens the login page (MSAL) and when I try to login (the actual program redirects to localhost:8054)

but sometimes it is opening the first default web-app I ran why this is happening.
the index.html is different.
the below is the $web container


Can you share your GitHub repo here?

I don't have any github I'm doing locally

I have enabled the Static website in the Azure storage like this and liked on the web to upload the index.html file.

I uploaded the index.html file as this.

Have you uploaded the index.html file like me or not?

I could see the static website in Azure storage in the browser. This is my first Flutter app's web> index.html, another after-update.

I just created a normal index.html for Dashboard. If possible can you share your code with the dashboard and index.html?

I followed the azure documentation and uploaded the index.html (Yes like yours) also uploaded some supporting files like assets, icons, and main.dart.js and loader.css.

What is your dashboard code? Can you share it in the question?

Unfortunately I can't able to share the code

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I sent the code in chat
